# A characterization of flat metrics via global vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let  $(M,g)$ be  a  Riemannian  manifold with $LC$ conncection $\nabla$.
Assume  that for  every three  **global** vector  fields $X,Y,Z \in \chi^{\infty}(M)$ with $[X,Y]=0$  we  have $\nabla_{X} \nabla_{Y} Z=\nabla_{Y} \nabla_{X} Z$

> Is  the  metric necessarily   a  flat  metric?

Comment: Are you only allowed to check this condition for vector fields that are globally defined on $M$?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  yes in fact how can two locall commting vector fields can be extend to two global commuting vector fields?

Comment: Moreover in the litterature, are there some focus on flat manifolds with the following dynamical approach: two commuting flows give two commuting connection operators.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  according to a conjecture a generic diffeomorphisms admit no nontrivial centralizer, so is it obvious we have a global commuting vector fields which are independent at almost all points?

Comment: The conjecture about centralizers of generic diffeomorphisms is actually proved in the $C^1$ case. https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1416

Comment: @VítTuček  Thank you very  much  for  the  link of the  paper  by  C. Bonatti et all. I also  thank you sincerely  for  your  revision of  my question.

Comment: Some googling turned up http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4520/v15/oppgaver/oblig.pdf - assuming problem 4 is correct, we can construct commuting global vector fields $X,Y$ with prescribed values at a single point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $g$ is flat, we need enough pairs of commuting global vector fields. To construct these, let $f(r)\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,1)$ be a monotone function with $f(r)=1-\frac1{\log r}$ for $r\gg 1$. Consider the diffeomorphism $\mathbb R^n\to B^n$ given by $\Phi(x)=f(|x|)\,\frac x{|x|}$. We can map constant (and therefore commuting) vector fields $V$, $W$ on $\mathbb R^n$ to vector fields on $B^n$ that decay sufficiently fast near the boundary of $B^n\subset\mathbb R^n$ so that we can extend them by $0$ to compactly supported vector fields $\bar V$, $\bar W$ on $\mathbb R^n$. By naturality of the Lie bracket, these vector fields still commute.

The same construction in local coordinates gives sufficiently  many pairs of commuting vector field of manifolds to conclude that the connection $\nabla$ is flat.

In the comments you ask for global vector fields that are independent almost everywhere. It seems to me that the construction above can be modified to give pairs of commuting vector fields that vanish along the $(n-1)$-skeleton of a smooth triangulation of a manifold $M$, and are linearly independent otherwise.

Comment: With the old $f$, the vector fields would not decay fast enough on $B^n$ close to the boundary. So I copied the function used in the link in @Anthony Carapetis' comment instead.